# Different color shades for faceted grouped bar plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I'm trying to give different shades of the same color to the grouped bar plots that are also faceted.

Here is the code and the output that I already have:

```
temp.data = data.frame (Species  = rep(c("A","B"),each=2, times=2),
                        Status = rep(c("An","Bac"), times=4),
                        Sex = rep(c("Male","Female"), each=4, times=1),
                        Proportion = c(6.86, 7.65, 30.13, 35.71, 7.13, 10.33, 29.24, 31.09))

ggplot(temp.data, aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status, alpha = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width=.67) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) + xlab("X title") + 
  ylab("Y title") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Status", labels = c("An","Bac"),
                    values = c("#86a681","#0a3e03")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.6, 1)) +
  theme_light() + theme(legend.title= element_text(size = 8),
                        legend.title.align=0.5,
                        legend.position = c(),
                        legend.background=element_blank(),
                        legend.text=element_text(size=7),
                        legend.key.size = unit(0.6, 'cm'),
                        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y.right = element_text("Sex of groups"),
                        strip.background = element_rect(
                          color="lightgrey", fill="white", size=0.5, linetype="solid"),
                        strip.text.y = element_text(color = "darkgrey", face = "bold"))
```

[image]

However, I couldn't find an answer here to give different colors for different bar groups. I came up with the `scale_alpha_manual()` function eventually but it can't be given colors manually, it should be the alpha scales of defined "fill". Therefore, this question also isn't a duplicate question here.

Here's how the desired output should seem like (preferably with the legends):
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So in this case, A=orange and B=light green both represent "An"? How do you imagine the legend?

Comment: @zx8754 So darker shades will belong to Status: Bac whereas lighter shades will be Status: An. Either I think the legend should show duplicate statuses for different darker and lighter colors such as: legend title will be Status again and two dark colored boxes will be labeled as Bac and two lighter shaded boxes will be labeled ad An. Honestly it sounds complicated with ggplot2 aesthetics to me. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ggnewscale` package.  Below, I made subsets of the data for species A and B separately.  Then, I made the species A bars with one set of colours and then called `new_scale_fill()` which initializes a new fill scale.  Then, I made the species B bars with different colours.  Both bars will have an associated set of colours and a legend that can be set with `scale_fill_manual()`.

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
temp.data = data.frame (Species  = rep(c("A","B"),each=2, times=2),
                        Status = rep(c("An","Bac"), times=4),
                        Sex = rep(c("Male","Female"), each=4, times=1),
                        Proportion = c(6.86, 7.65, 30.13, 35.71, 7.13, 10.33, 29.24, 31.09))

tempA <- temp.data %>% filter(Species == "A")
tempB <- temp.data %>% filter(Species == "B")


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = tempB, 
           mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status), 
           stat='identity', 
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), 
           width=.67) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Species", 
                    labels = c("An","Bac"),
                    values = c("#86a681","#0a3e03"),
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=c("gray75", "gray25")))) + 
  new_scale_fill() + 
  geom_bar(data = tempA, 
           mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status), 
           stat='identity', 
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), 
           width=.67, show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Species A: Status", 
                    labels = c("An","Bac"),
                    values = c("brown2","brown4")) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) + 
  xlab("X title") + 
  ylab("Y title") + 
  theme_light() + theme(legend.title= element_text(size = 8),
                        legend.title.align=0.5,
                        legend.position = c(),
                        legend.background=element_blank(),
                        legend.text=element_text(size=7),
                        legend.key.size = unit(0.6, 'cm'),
                        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y.right = element_text("Sex of groups"),
                        strip.background = element_rect(
                          color="lightgrey", fill="white", linewidth=0.5, linetype="solid"),
                        strip.text.y = element_text(color = "darkgrey", face = "bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It seems great but is there a way to merge the legends of two different temp data, since the statuses are the same? Or a better option would be grouping the light-colored boxes together and dark-colored ones together in legend? I'm asking this because it takes scales manually from different temp data, however, legends work in the same theme function.

Comment: What  would you want the legend to look like?

Comment: It could be light and dark-colored boxes grouped together under just one legend title called "Status". Therefore, it'd be only one "An" Status written next to the light-colored boxes and one "Bac" status next to the dark-colored boxes. Does it make sense?

Comment: I update the answer with a plausible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can also see what kind of sub-arguments I can play with if necessary so this answer makes it actually better.

Answer (score 2):

We can set colours based one column, then add shade based on another column:

```
# create custom colours per Species
cols <- ifelse(temp.data$Species == "A", "red", "blue")

# change to lighter shade for An
ix <- which(temp.data$Status == "An")
cols[ ix ] <- sapply(cols[ ix ], function(i) colorRampPalette(c("white", i))(10)[ 5 ])
cols <- setNames(cols, temp.data$grp)

# fill group
temp.data$grp = paste(temp.data$Species, temp.data$Status)

# plot with fill manual
ggplot(temp.data, aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width = 0.67) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, too. It'd be especially handy when you need to label all bars in the same and different groups. Thanks!